# Threshold function of the property Sperner set

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics, probabilistic-method

Someone can to help me in the following problem about the threshold function of the property *Sperner set*? I don't know where to start.

> Let $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{P}([n])$ be a random family of subsets with $\mathbf{Pr}(A\in \mathcal{F}) = p(n)$, for all $A\subseteq [n]$ (independently). Show that $p_0(n) = 3^{-n/2}$ is a threshold function for the event "*$\mathcal{F}$ is Sperner*", i.e.,
>   $$
> \mathbf{Pr}(\mathcal{F} \text{ is Sperner}) \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \left\{
>   \begin{array}{ll}
>     0, & \text{if }\; p(n) \ll p_0(n) \hbox{;} \\
>     1, & \text{if }\; p(n) \gg p_0(n)\hbox{.}
>   \end{array}
> \right.
> $$

Note: $\mathcal{F}$ is Sperner if $\forall A,B \in \mathcal{F}$, we have $A \not\subseteq B$ and $B \not\subseteq A$.